# What is the minimum raise after an all-in?

Tags: texas-hold-em, no-limit, all-in, sit-and-go, raise

I am hosting a home game (NL Texas Hold'em sit N go), and would like to make sure we get all the rules right, but there is one situation that I'm having trouble with. What is the minimum raise after an all-in?

I think that there are three cases for an all-in:

1. All-in is less than the current bet
2. All-in is at least the current bet, but less than a minimum raise
3. All-in is at least a minimum raise

The first case clearly doesn't change the minimum raise and the third case clearly does; the second case is the one that I am uncertain about.

Suppose we have the following bets after the flop:

```
Player 1: Bets 200
Player 2: Raises to 600
Player 3: All-in
Player 4: Raise
```

I understand that the all-in (for < 1000 chips) does not allow Player 2 to re-raise unless there is another raise between them. What I don't know is how much Player 4 must bet to meet a minimum raise.

Situation 1: Suppose Player 3 had 700 chips. Is Player 4 able to raise to 1000 (calculated by ignoring the all-in), do they need to raise to 1100 (adding the previous minimum raise of 400 to the all-in amount). I doubt they'd be able to raise by only `700-600 = 100 chips`.

Suppose Player 3 had 999 chips. Is Player 4 able to re-open betting by raising to 1000, or would they need to raise to 1399, or maybe 1398?

My guess is that Player 4 can always raise to 1000, if the all-in was less than a minimum raise, but I would like some verification before I host the game.

Comment: From what I know, in the situation you presented (player 3 has 700 and goes all-in), player 4 must raise a minimum of 600 - 200 = 400 more chips on top of player 3's total, so raise to 1100. But I would have to find some rulebook to be certain and I will post it as an answer in that case.

Answer (score 4):

• The minimum legal raise is equal to the previous raise amount.

• If the previous all-in raise amount was less than the minimum raise, then the minimum raise is equal to the previous minimum raise.

• If a player goes all-in for less than the minimum legal raise after the open raiser, and is called by at least another player, the open raiser will only be able to call or fold, because the all-in is not at least equal to the minimum raise.

Example :

UTG raises 200. CO goes all-in for 275. BTN calls. Action back to UTG. UTG can only call or fold.

Look at the hand as if the all-in player had only called, and everything should be clearer.

Comment: My question is, what would BTN need to qualify as a raise in that situation? 350, 400, or 475?

Comment: if blinds are 50/100 : 375. • If the previous raise amount was less than a big blind, then the minimum raise is equal to the big blind.

Comment: That doesn't seem to make sense. Suppose the blinds are 50/100, then UTG raises to 5000, then UTG+1 goes all-in for 5050. Then the UTG+2 can't raise to 5150. I'm sure they would need to raise to at least 9900. I'm just not sure if it's 9900, 9950, 10000, or something else.

Comment: I wrote the rule in an awkward way. In this example, UTG made more than a minraise, and UTG+1 didn't equal the minimum raise when going all-in. The legal minraise here is 9950, as UTG made a raise of +4900. I've edited my answer to take that into account. This link should help you : http://neilwebber.com/notes/2013/07/25/the-most-misunderstood-poker-rule-nlhe-incomplete-raise-all-in/